# unable to run the scripts in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

Running the pgsql script in pgadmin but getting errors which seemingly look like syntax isn't recognized. I used the latest postgres documentation to verify my syntax and seems like it's okay.

here is the script

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DECLARE rootId smallInt := 100


INSERT INTO security.module(moduleid, title, description) VALUES (1, 'module 1', 'some description');
INSERT INTO security.module(moduleid, title, description) VALUES (200, 'module 2', 'description');

SAVEPOINT modules_added;
COMMIT;
```

I got errors on begin transacion, commit, savepoint, declare... basically anything that was not INSERT, UPDATE, CREATE, DELETE. How can I make pgsql recogize these statements which are causing errors.

Update: as [@a_horse_with_no_legs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) asked, here is the code with thr error message:

[image]

Comment: `declare` can only be used inside a PL/pgSQL (to define a block where PL/pgSQL variables are defined). It's not a SQL command and can't be used in plain SQL. If you want to use PL/pgSQL you need to put that into a  `DO` [block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html). Btw: the savepoint right before the COMMIT makes no sense.

Comment: 1. I tried DO block and errors are still the same  2. this is just a sample script so I trimmed it but not logically corrected it because that wasn't the point

Comment: If you want help with the error message, then show us the complete real code and the complete error message

Comment: First step read [plpgsql structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) where you will find: "A common mistake is to write a semicolon immediately after BEGIN. This is incorrect and will result in a syntax error.".From same link,  is because:"...PL/pgSQL's BEGIN/END are only for grouping; they do not start or end a transaction."